# Alternative CDI approach to subclassing?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

This is my working code at the moment:

```
public enum Year 
{
    year2021,
    year2022;
}
```

_

```
public class Zoo 
{
    private Year year;
    
    public Zoo(Year year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }
    
    public int predictNumberOfAnimals() { ... }
}
```

_

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface YearAnnotation 
{
    String value();
}
```

_

```
public class Zoo2021 extends Zoo
{
    @Inject 
    public Zoo2021(@YearAnnotation("y2021") Year year)
    {
        super(year);
    }
    
    @Produces @YearAnnotation("y2021")
    public static Year getYear()
    {
        return Year.year2021;
    }
}
```

_

```
public class Zoo2022 extends Zoo
{
    @Inject 
    public Zoo2022(@YearAnnotation("y2022") Year year)
    {
        super(year);
    }
    
    @Produces @YearAnnotation("y2022")
    public static Year getYear()
    {
        return Year.year2022;
    }
}
```

Then this works:

```
public class Client
{
    @Inject 
    private Zoo2022 zoo2022;
    
    @Inject 
    private Zoo2021 zoo2021;
}
```

---

However, I don't like having to create a subclass of `Zoo` for each new `Year`. Let's assume that passing `Year` as a parameter to `predictNumberOfAnimals` is not an option.

Is it possible to avoid subclassing and do something like the following?:

```
public class Zoo 
{
    private Year year;
    
    @Inject
    public Zoo(Year year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }
    
    public int predictNumberOfAnimals() { ... }
}
```

_

```
pulic class Client
{
    @Inject @YearAnnotation("y2021") // <- (*)
    private Zoo zoo2021;
    
    @Inject @YearAnnotation("y2022") // <- (*)
    private Zoo zoo2022;

    @Produces @YearAnnotation("y2021")
    public static Year getYear2021()
    {
        return Year.year2021;
    }
    
    @Produces @YearAnnotation("y2022")
    public static Year getYear2022()
    {
        return Year.year2022;
    }
}
```

With the `@YearAnnotation` annotations at `(*)` I want to signalize that when creating the respective `Zoo` instance the respective (different) year should be injected (via the constructor of `Zoo`). My idea was to somehow bind a `@Produces` method to an instance variable.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get the injection point in a producer method, evaluate the annotation from there, and init the concrete object according to the value of the annotation. Note that the concrete value in the annotation needs to be nonbinding in this case:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface YearAnnotation 
{
    @Nonbinding
    String value();
}
```

The producer method:

```
@Produces @YearAnnotation Zoo makeZoo(InjectionPoint ip) {
    String yearValue = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(YearAnnotation.class).value();
    ... create zoo, init with yearValue, return
}
```

The injection just as you already posted it

```
@Inject @YearAnnotation("y2021")
private Zoo zoo2021;

@Inject @YearAnnotation("y2022")
private Zoo zoo2022;
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of `InjectionPoint`. To make your example work, I have to default `value` in `YearAnnotation` to some value, otherwise `@YearAnnotation` won't be accepted at the `@Producer` method. I also had to remove the `@Inject` at `Zoo`s constructor.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is the best approach though. Imagine I additionally have a `Country` in which a `Zoo` shall be injected. In the same manner `@YearAnnotation("...")` shall indicate which `Zoo` to inject into `Country`. Following your solution, I then would add a `@Produces @YearAnnotation Country makeCountry(InjectionPoint ip)` method. Inside I'd do something like `return new Country(new Zoo(yearValue))`, wouldn't I? I'm wondering if this is good because then I'd chain `new`s inside this method. Isn't this something we want to avoid with Dependency Injection?

Comment: How does this approach compare to the approach I came up with in the answer I just posted? Following the approach stated there, I could add two analogous methods for `makeCountry`. IMHO, the benefit would be that there is only one `new` per method; the downside would be more methods.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to add `@Produces` methods for `Zoo`s. These use the `Year` instances given by the `@Produces` methods already stated in the question.

```
@Produces @YearAnnotation("y2021")
public static Zoo makeZooYear2021(@YearAnnotation("y2021") Year year)
{
    return new Zoo(year);
}

@Produces @YearAnnotation("y2022")
public static Zoo makeZooYear2022(@YearAnnotation("y2022") Year year)
{
    return new Zoo(year);
}
```

To make this work, `@Inject` at the `Zoo` constructor has to be removed.

Comment: Is it possible to improve this by somehow combining these two functions into one function?